# where can I find the spring boot 3.1.3 property name to override reactor-netty-http version

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3

where can I find the correct spring boot (v3.1.3) property name - that I can use in my pom.xml to override the default **reactor-netty-http** *version* (in "spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty") ?

For example, I found I could use the property name "netty.version" in my pom.xml to override the  **netty-codec-http2** *version*
i.e.,
<netty.version>4.1.106.Final</netty.version>

where can I find the correct spring boot property name to override the **reactor-netty-http** *version*?

thx :-)

Comment: That should be the same, but why do you want to meddle with the version in the first place?

Comment: to address anchor-grype reported vulnerabilities on existing code - thx for asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find Spring Boot dependency version properties [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions.properties).